# Copying mp3 file in android

Tags: android

I have a requirement where I have to copy mp3 file from other device.Though it is copied successfully through java.io operation but it isnot listing that mp3 file in music player list.

Answer (score 2):

You have to notify the MediaStore that you added a new file. 
You can do it this way after saving the mp3:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(mp3File)));
```